# Problems with 2 different GUI windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, tk-toolkit

So my first GUI window is meant for taking input from user :

```
from tkinter import *
from main import *


root = Tk()

root.configure(background="orange")
root.wm_title("Python Project")

label_1 = Label(root, text="Project Name",bg="orange",fg="black")
label_2 = Label(root, text="Site URL Link",bg="orange",fg="black")
entry_1 = Entry(root)
entry_2 = Entry(root)

label_1.grid(row=0,sticky=W)
label_2.grid(row=3333,sticky=W)

entry_1.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=50,ipadx=100)
entry_2.grid(row=3333,column=1,ipadx=100)

def callback():
    a1 = entry_1.get()
    a2 = entry_2.get()
    mmm(a1,a2,root) # main program


button1 = Button(root,text="Run",command=callback)
button2=Button(root,text="Quit",command=root.quit)

button1.grid(row=3334,ipadx=15,padx=50,column=1)
button2.grid(row=3335,column=1,ipadx=15,padx=50)


root.mainloop()
```

And then i use another GUI window someone in this forum made to show my results :

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
textbox = Text(root)
textbox.pack()

def redirector(inputStr):
    textbox.insert(INSERT, inputStr)

sys.stdout.write = redirector  # whenever sys.stdout.write is called, redirector is called.
sys.stderr.write = redirector

root.mainloop()
```

Now every time i run the first GUI , both GUIs open although there is no way the code reached the second GUI code yet... What is the problem here?

Also the second GUI is supposed to print from a class , but i have a bunch of error when I try to just put it there . What changes I need to make so I can make this 2nd GUI work with a class?

Comment: This is because when you import the `main` module you are effectively running that program.

Comment: the other gui is a diffrent class , not main ....

Comment: `from main import *` I assume this is the "GUI window someone in this forum made". If that is the case, this code will load first (this window will be generated), and then your code will run.

Comment: I tend to agree with Sithling. Anyways, why run this as two different GuIs? It seems as if you just want a popup ? - What are you trying to do ?

Comment: @svendfeldt after the user input , my program will have alot of prints for user information , so i want to show it some .. i have threads that use class functions that print and i think mainloop screws everything up .... idk what to do